# JavaScript - How to determine if a letter is surrounded by a symbol?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to solve a JavaScript coding exercise and my code is wrong and I can't see why.

The task is:

> take a string and if every letter in the string is surrounded by a '+' sign, return true, otherwise return false.

It works for most cases but doesn't work for '=a+' for example and I don't understand why. Could someone explain?

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        if (str[0].match(/[a-z]/i) || str[str.length - 1].match(/[a-z]/i)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (str[i].match(/[a-z]/i) && (str[i - 1] !== "+" || str[i + 1] !== "+")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
}

SimpleSymbols(readline());
```

Comment: Couldn't you skip the loop entirely and just use a regex to look for any letters which aren't preceded or followed by a plus sign? Something like `return !/(^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z]([^+]|$)/i.test(str);`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the inner `else` clause. It should be elimninated, and instead, the function should return `true` after the `for` block.

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        if (str[0].match(/[a-z]/i) || str[str.length - 1].match(/[a-z]/i)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (str[i].match(/[a-z]/i) && (str[i - 1] !== "+" || str[i + 1] !== "+")) {
                return false;
            } 
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Like the OP's code, this will exit the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks, @nnnnnn. Fixed.

Comment: Cool. +1. Note that the first `if` could probably be eliminated too: I don't think there's any need to treat the first and last characters differently, because `str[-1]` and `str[str.length]` will just give `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you all! @ you said the it would exit the loop on the 1st iteration and I wonder why it is a problem: every letter must be surrounded by a + sign. If the first letter in the string is not surrounded by a plus sign, its okay to already exiting the loop because it doesn't matter if other letters are surrounded by + as all have to be and if one letter is not it should return false anyway.

Comment: Also I still don't understand why in the case the string is '=a+' the result is true.Since = is not a letter, it goes into the else statement. Then I say return false if str[i].match(/[a-z]/i) && (str[i - 1] !== "+" || str[i + 1] !== "+") -since = is not + , a is not surrounded by + so it should return false. How does it even go into the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Could you match against this and return the result:

```
^\+(?:[a-z]\+)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/1zXUJD/1

looks for strings that start with a '+' and then any number of [a-z]+ after that until the end of the string.